# how to add disabled option to React Native Picker

Tags: react-native, picker

I am creating a react native app. I have tried to create drop-downs with react native . its working fine for me. I am tried to add default option like "Please select option......". I have tried it but not working for me.
my code is:-

```
<Picker
    mode="dropdown"
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({selectedItem: itemValue})}>
    {subchild['OptionValue'].map((subsubchild, Index3)=>
        <Picker.Item label={subsubchild['text']} value={subsubchild['id']} />
    )}
</Picker>
```

I have tried it like this :-

```
<Picker
    mode="dropdown"
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({selectedItem: itemValue})}>     <Picker.Item label="Please select options....." value="0" />
    {subchild['OptionValue'].map((subsubchild, Index3)=>
        <Picker.Item label={subsubchild['text']} value={subsubchild['id']} />
    )}
</Picker>
```

Its not working exactly I want.

Comment: In short, not possible atm.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the example for you:

```
<Picker
    mode="dropdown"
    selectedValue={this.state.selectedItem}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({selectedItem: itemValue})}>     <Picker.Item label="Please select options....." value="0" />
    {subchild['OptionValue'].map((subsubchild, Index3)=>
        <Picker.Item label={subsubchild['text']} value={subsubchild['id']} />
    )}
</Picker>
```

You should set the default selected value into your state **selectedItem**

> this.state = {selectedItem: '0'};

In the Process of State-Change, you should set condition if selected value equal to **zero** then **return** what you want.

Hope it will help you.

Please refer to the link below for more detail.

> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.19/picker.html#mode

Comment: as i mentioned above, i have tried this and its not working properly, when i have selected any item from drop-downs than its showing behind the please select options...... its messed up the content

Comment: Please read my answer above more clearly @kiranbghrix.
Your code missing **"selectedValue={this.state.selectedItem}"**

Comment: Hi @kiranbghrix, if it is what you looking for, please mark it as **Answer** prevent from other to answer it again. Thx